# Can sql server queries be really cancelled/killed?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I would like to give a user the ability to cancel a running query. The query is really slow. (Query optimization is besides the point.) This is mainly out of my curiosity.

MSDN says:

> If there is nothing to cancel, nothing occurs. However, if there is a
>   command in process, and the attempt to cancel fails, no exception is
>   generated.

- Cmd            - SqlCommand
- DA             - DataAdapter
- Conn           - SqlConnection
- CurrentSearch  - Thread
- LongQuery      - Singleton

Here's what I have:

```
var t = new Thread(AbortThread);
t.Start();

void AbortThread()
{
    LongQuery.Current.Cmd.Cancel();
    LongQuery.Current.Cmd.Dispose();
    LongQuery.Current.DA.Dispose();
    LongQuery.Current.Conn.Close();
    LongQuery.Current.Conn.Dispose();
    LongQuery.Current.Cmd = null;
    LongQuery.Current.DA = null;
    LongQuery.Current.Conn = null;
    CurrentSearch.Abort();
    CurrentSearch.Join();
    CurrentSearch = null;
}
```

I noticed that `CurrentSearch.Abort()` was blocking, that's why I wrapped it in a thread, which probably means that the thread is still working.

Finally, is there anything else than this that I can do to cancel a query? Is it actually possible to cancel such a long query from .NET?

Comment: Is the query writing data, or just reading it?

Comment: @BrianKnight Just reading from multiple views.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IF you really absolutely want to kill it for good use this approach:

- store away the session ID right before starting the long-running query by calling [`SELECT @@SPID AS 'SESSIONID'`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189535.aspx) on the same connection

When you want to kill it:

- Open a new DB connection
- issue a [`KILL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx) command for that session ID
  BEWARE as the MSDN documentation states you need the permission `ALTER ANY CONNECTION` to do this

Comment: The KILL command requires an elevated permission - ALTER ANY CONNECTION.

Comment: Can we use transaction.rollback() here.

Comment: @m.qayyum what do you mean ? the query to be aborted is long-running... the KILL will rollback any transaction pending in this regard (even distributed ones)... and AFAIK what you suggest works only on the connection that is running the transaction but that connection is busy so I am pretty sure that this would just block or throw an exception but in essence do nothing regarding stopping the long-running query...

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can kill a process from .NET. [Here is an example](http://weblogs.asp.net/stanleygu/archive/2010/03/31/tip-13-kill-a-process-from-local-to-remote.aspx). Please note you will need proper permissions and you have to figure out the process in question. I don't have a quick sample of determining which process your query is running under.

You example aborts the thread, but that does not mean the work on SQL Server was terminated. If you think about it this way: when you go through a bad cell zone and the call drops, if you mom/wife/friend was droning on, do they instantly stop talking? That is an analogy of aborting the thread, at least in the case of working with a database server.

Comment: He's trying to kill an in-progress query, not a process.