# Using a thread to timeout a ADO.NET query

Tags: c#, multithreading, ado.net

I have a need to run a query on a couple different ADO.NET connection types (Sql and Oracle). I want to have the ability to cancel the query after X seconds if it has not yet completed.  I thought a thread might be a good way to approach this, so I could just kill the thread after X seconds, if it's still alive:

```
var thread = new Thread((param) =>
{
    try
    {
        string connStr = "****";
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connStr);
        try
        {                       
            conn.Open();
            Debug.WriteLine("Connection Open: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(param as string, conn);
            Debug.WriteLine("Command Start: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            Debug.WriteLine("Command End: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            conn.Close();
            Debug.WriteLine("Connection Close: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Cancel: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }
});

Debug.WriteLine("Start: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

thread.Start("begin dbms_lock.sleep(10); end;"); 
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
while (thread.IsAlive)
{
    if (DateTime.Now > start.AddSeconds(5))
    {
        thread.Interrupt();
    }
}                

Debug.WriteLine("End: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
```

However, this is not cancelling with the `thread.Interrupt()` like other code I've used before.

How can I get this to work, or is there a better way to approach this issue?

Comment: You have to kill the sql connection first, here it shows how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837739/can-sql-server-queries-be-really-cancelled-killed

Comment: In my scenario, I care less about the actual query on the DB, and more about continuing my process.  I also would not have the necessary permission to kill the query.

Comment: Is this code running in asp.net or windows forms?

Comment: It's part of an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: Great, then use Web API and make a timeout for that web api call.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this. Can you provide a url to more info?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [ASP.NET Web Api Controller](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) that encapsulates your sql query, in your MVC Controller use a [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx) and specify a timeout to your request to the api. The Web API call will return a JSON object containing the query result, you'll need to deserialize it in your controller using [JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316.aspx).

Comment: Is this class available in .NET4? I can't seem to find the System.Web.Http dll.