# Can we cancel query issued to sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, ado.net

I have a complex piece of SQL and it involves lot of calculations etc. I want to know whether it is possible to cancel the query that is issued to the SQL server?

Ex. There is a button named Search and user clicks on Search. I want to show a button named "Cancel" and that should cancel the query issued to the SQL server.

Is this possible?

Comment: Since you can do it in Management Studio, I strongly would believe that you also can do it on your own. See also [Asynchronous Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw97wx20.aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: Use a transaction and rollback? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935900/how-to-commit-and-rollback-transaction-in-sql-server

Comment: may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837739/can-sql-server-queries-be-really-cancelled-killed

Comment: @Jack Which part seems unclear to me?

Comment: @UweKeim: "Since you can do it in Management Studio, I strongly would believe that you also can do it on your own.". Please don't post blind comments without understanding the question. Further you gave a link to .Net 4.5 even though I have tagged my question as C# 4.

Comment: SqlCommand has a Cancel method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel.aspx

Comment: The question 'Is this possible?' is perfectly answered by @UweKeim

Comment: @rene: Answer should be in context. I could very well say shut down the machine..the query will be cancelled. That doesn't however answer this question and perhaps also should try to read the whole question rather than just reading the end line.

Comment: +1, and the answer is "Yes" 8-/

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of asynchron functions in ADO.NET, e.g. [`SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca56w9se%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You can call these functions in your application, store the result object and cancel it when the user clicks the "Cancel" button.

So in pseudo-code you can do these steps:

1. User clicks the <kbd>Search</kbd> button.
2. In the button's handler, open your DB connection and the like.
3. Show your <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button.
4. Call the ADO.NET async function of your choice.
5. Store the `IAsyncResult` returned object of the function call (for detecting when the operation has finished to hide the cancel button again).
6. In the cancel button's handler, call the [`Cancel` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Thanks!! That really gave me a clue :) and is better than giving access of server details to my users :)